# Posting External Images on Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an Android app that displays images organized in albums. The albums and images are fetched from a web server. I'd like to be able to share either one or more images (or an entire album) on my Facebook timeline or a friend's timeline. I don't want to use the share functionality of the device (too cumbersome), but would like to build in the sharing logic into my application. Furthermore, I don't want to upload images from my device to FB, but simply send URLs to the images (or should it be a server query command that returns the URLs themselves?) On the FB page, I'd like these images to be viewable just like normally uploaded FB images are viewable. Can someone please point me in the right direction on how to get started? Do I need to write a FB App to support this or is there a much simpler way to do this? If I have N images, can I just upload N URLs? And what exactly does it mean to upload to FB without going through the FB app itself? A bit overloaded question, but any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can share custom feed actions using Open Graph Actions.

See this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share-dialog/#publishogactions

I don't know if it is possible to reproduce the same effect as uploading pictures directly to facebook. In any case you will have to declare your app in the FB Dev console for sharing through your app.

Comment: Thank You, this is exactly what I was looking for to get started.